# How do I get my columns printed in a canvas on tkinter in python to be aligned to the right? Notice how some columns are shifted to the right

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Here is my python code making the table. It is a *DataFrame* being printed using the `to_string()` method.

```py
# part to convert DataFrame to string  
df_concat = df_concat.to_string()
# inserting DataFrame into canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,
                    background="white",
                    width=width,
                    height=height)
canvas.create_text((500, 1000), text=df_concat)
```

[image: table misaligned]

Comment: you have to use different font - one of so called `monospace` fonts. It will have all chars with the same width (like font in console/terminal) and it will display aligned like in console/terminal. OR you will have to print every cell in every column as separted element on canvas.

Comment: maybe you should use module `pandastable` to display `dataframe` - [Tkinter PandasTable Examples](https://blog.furas.pl/python-tkinter-pandastable-examples-gb.html)